Is there any way to get the timeline from Nao Robot in python?
Let's say we have a current movement set in the timeline (like a dance). Is there any way that we could get the movement attached in the timeline through Python code?

You can export it as a python or c++ code.
Open the timeline in choregraphe and right-click on the key line, then export to c++ or python.
